# Break from async function in await call

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Okay, so I'm working with data from Memcache using a promise based library but the issue I'm having is I don't know a way to break from the async call if a result is found?

The code I'm working with is:

```
        const _pong = function() {
            return socket.emit('aye', {
                pong: globals.uuid()
            });
        };
        return socket.on('helo', async function(data) {
            socket._uuid = data.uuid;
            let key = 'ws-ping:' + data.uuid;
            await cache.get(key).then((result) => {
                if(result !== undefined) {
                    _pong();
                }
            });
            ......
        });
```

I basically need to just ignore the rest of the `socket.on` function if a result is found using the given key? but it seems to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using `await`, you can ditch the `.then`, and get the `result` directly, in the same block - if the result exists, then just `return` (after `_pong`ing, if that's the logic you're looking for):

```
return socket.on('helo', async function(data) {
  socket._uuid = data.uuid;
  let key = 'ws-ping:' + data.uuid;
  const result = await cache.get(key);
  if (result !== undefined) {
    _pong();
    return;
  }
  // ...
});
```